# How to align icon in material Grid item to the right always even screen change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, right-align

I learn JavaScript React and now I have this question:

I have this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-new-content-done-icon-bipxs?file=/src/FileEditor.jsx)

The problem I can't get the icon on the image below to stay to the right of the `input`

[image]

I want it to be like this:

[image]

I have tried using material `Grid` in various ways but I think I don't understand how to use wrapping, like `wrap="nowrap"`.

I also tried like `<Grid item style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 5, right: 5 }}>` but the icon is outside the `container`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a `display: flex` in the tag that includes the input and the icon instead of grids.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ it may help you.

```js
<div className="Test">
     <input className="form-control"
            placeholder="File Title"
            value={"theTitle"}
            type="text"/>
      <Avatar />
</div>
```

and the css is just

```css
.Test {
 display: flex;
}
```

Comment: I [tried](https://snipboard.io/hTeKiO.jpg) that but not difference really strange

Comment: I also tried like `<Grid item style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 5, right: 5 }}>` but the icon is outside the `container` so funny
`

Comment: @Kid in your screenshot you put the `div=className"Test`around the input, and you create another around the icons. But check how I made it in my example above. The input and the icon you wan to be aligned needs to be in the same `div`.